# Java loops- display every integer between two integers

Tags: java, loops

I am new to coding and have been trying to understand loops. I am working on a sample project that says to Write an application that prompts a user for two integers and displays every integer between them. Display a message if there are no integers between the entered values. Make sure the program works regardless of which entered value is larger. I for the most part have it but am having an issue with the output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int num1;
int num2;
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input one integer");
num1= input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter another integer");
num2= input.nextInt();

while(num1<num2) {
    num1 += 1;
    System.out.println(num1);
}
while(num2<num1){
    num2+=1;
    System.out.println(num2);
}


}
}
```

A sample output would be

```
Input one integer

1

Enter another integer
9
```

Then this is the output
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: You increment `num1` before you print it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that. It works correctly except it prints out 9. The project says to print every integer between the two inputted integers. 9 was one that was entered and it printed it out.

Comment: If I increment num1 after I print it, it goes from 1-8. Which would be the same issue I had when I printed num1 before.

Comment: 8 is less then 9 so you enter the loop one more time and print 8+1. I would simply add 1 to the smallest number before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As you are incrementing value first so you can try this approach

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int num1;
int num2;
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input one integer");
num1= input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter another integer");
num2= input.nextInt();
while(num1<num2-1) {
num1 += 1;
System.out.println(num1);
}
while(num2<num1-1){
num2+=1;
System.out.println(num2);
}


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop for this purpose. Though you would need to include some logic to ensure that num1 is the smaller of the two numbers.

Note the `num1 + 1` is there to make the first number non-inclusive.

---

A for-loop is broken down into 3 components

start: `i = num1 + 1`

condition: `i <= num2`
ensure `i` is less than or equal to num2

action: `i++`
after each iteration, `i` will be incremented by 1

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input one integer");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter another integer");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = num1 + 1; i <= num2; i++) {
            System.out.println(num2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to get a perfect score.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Inbetween {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x, y, X, Y;
        X = input.nextInt();
        Y = input.nextInt();
        if (Y+1 == X || X+1 == Y ){ 
            System.out.print("There are no integers between " + X + " and " + Y);                   
        }else if (Y>X){
            for(x=X+1; x<Y; ++x)
                System.out.print(x+" "); 
        }else if (X>Y){
            for(y=Y+1; y<X; ++y)
                System.out.print(y+" ");
        }
    }
}
```